# How do I post a complex string using Jquery $.post?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need help passing a complex string representing a polygon to a php script where the string is used in an SQL query.  The proper format is to enclose the entire POLYGON statement in single quotes.  The PHP script isn't catching the `$_POST` variable.  What could be the reason?

Javascript:

```
var polyBoundary = "'POLYGON ((-98.13787244260311 30.031055426540206, -95.98455213010311 31.970803930433096, -92.18328259885311 27.89734922968426, -95.69890759885311 26.49024045886963, -98.13787244260311 30.031055426540206))'";

$.post("php/insertPolygon.php", {boundary: polyBoundary}, function (data) {
    alert(data) // this alert never fires
    // Do stuff with the response
}, "json");
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    $prjBoundary = $_POST['boundary']; # I'll sanitize once I get everything working
    # Connect to DB, execute SQL query, etc.

    # Make sure I'm sending a response no matter what
    if ( ($errors = sqlsrv_errors() ) !=null) {
        echo "Error!";
    } else {
        echo "SUCCESS!"; # this should have been echo json_encode("SUCCESS!");
    }
```

PHP Error: `Undefined index: boundary in FILENAME on line 2`

Comment: neither the request nor the return data is `json`

Comment: a u sure that sending on right url (`php/insertPolygon.php`)?

Comment: what gives a print_r($_POST) in your PHP?

Comment: @voodoo417 how would he know what error he's getting if it were a wrong url

Comment: @php_nub_qq I dont know how he do testing. But i am sure problem in url

Comment: @php_nub_qq I wan't encoding the response as JSON.  Not sure how I overlooked that; everything is ironed out now, thanks.